# Finding the first coefficients of a power series.

Tags: calculus

I've been given a function $f(x)=\dfrac{2}{1+9x^2}$ and been asked to get the first few coefficients of its power series representation.

This looks like the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n x^n}=\dfrac{a}{1-x}: |x|<1$, so I did the following to get the power series representation:

$$f(x)=\frac{2}{1+9x^2} \textrm{, so my } a_n=2 \textrm{ and my } r=-9x^2$$
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(2)(-9x^2)^n} \textrm{, if } |-9x^2|<1$$

So from what I understand, to get the first few coefficients I should solve $(2)(-9x^2)^n$ for $n=0,1,2,3,4$. Doing this, I got:

$$(2)(-9x^2)^0=2x^0$$
$$(2)(-9x^2)^1=-18x^2$$
$$(2)(-9x^2)^2=162x^4$$
$$(2)(-9x^2)^3=-1458x^6$$
$$(2)(-9x^2)^4=13122x^8$$

So my coefficients should be $2, -18, 162, -1458,$ and $13122$. However, only $2$ is correct and the rest are wrong.

What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: The question might be asking for $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ to be the sequence such that $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ in some neighbourhood if $0$, whereas you are calling $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ the sequence such that $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{2n}$ in some neighbourhood of $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations are correct but you have to list coefficients of odd powers also. So the coefficients are $2,0,-18,0,162,0,...$.

Comment: This did the job, but I don't understand how I could get my coefficients to equal 0 given that don't think I can get the body of my series to equal 0.

Comment: @mars_plastic : A power series has terms of *all* (nonnegative integer) degrees.  What is the coefficient of the $x^1$ term in your series?

Comment: @EricTowers Ahh, I think I understand. So because my series is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(2)(-9)^n}(x^{2n})$, I'm skipping every odd degree because of the $2n$. So my coefficient for each odd degree would be 0?